# How do I install packages in pycharm venv?

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I've been using pycharm for a while now and I haven't really run into any problems until now, I just started a new project using Pygame and I started up pycharm and found that I could no longer install pygame. I have used it before in pycharm and had no problem. When I try to use pip I get this error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Alarm-1202\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xdvgbolk\pygame\
```

I have tried installing it outside pycharm and that works fine but it seems I don't have the same permissions inside the pycharm venv.

Comment: Try checking the official pycharm website: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010202240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was caused by an older version of pip which I didn't manage to fix but I could install pygame using easy_install instead.

Answer (score 0):

After opening pycharm terminal:

1. `python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip`
2. `pip install your_package_name`